# Is it possible to install BuddyPress with blogs installed on several servers?

Tags: multisite, buddypress, subscription

As far as I know, if you want to install BuddyPress you've got to have a WordPress MU installation (I know WordPress 3.x already is MU in itself) **with a unique database**, which has different tables for each blog.

But my situation is quite different: we have a blog network, and **we would like to have a buddypress installed** for all our blogs. This way users could register once and comment on the blogs automatically, see their activity, link to other users, etc. But **the blogs are on different servers** :(

Our current physical division of blogs (some of them are together in the same server, but others are in different servers, **each with its own database**) makes me think this is quite difficult to do. I know that the [Multi-DB plugin](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-db) could help us with the database thing, but... what if the blogs are, as in our situation, in different servers/VPS's?

Answer (score 1):

"As far as I know, if you want to install BuddyPress you've got to have a WordPress MU installation "

No, you do not. You can install BuddyPress on a single WordPRess installation.

If the blogs are all on different server,s then you do not have what is meant by a WordPress network (multisite - what WAS MU) and the multi DB plugin will not help you.

I can't see any way to do what you want without synching the user tables across everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could Setup a Multisite Network (formerly MU) and migrate existing wordpress sites to this network either manually or using a tool like backupbuddy which has a great multisite import tool. Then setup buddypress and then repoint dns to use the new sites. Just a thought. Oh and i highly recommend the multi-db plugin and running either a vps or cloud server with nginx if you intend on running multiple buddypress sites. Will make your sites lightning fast and fairly future proof.

Answer (score 0):

The lead developer of Buddypress said you can only install buddypress on one wordpress installation. Also what andrea_r said.

[BuddyPress on Multisite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41649/buddypress-on-multisite)